# PHPMailer doesn't work after Mailserver restart

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, phpmailer, exchange-server

I built a Ubuntu Server in our network segment and want it to send mail with PHPMailer. Mailserver and Webserver is in same segment (all in 192.168.37.XX).

Lastweek my mailserver was overload and I restarted it. after that, PHPMailer in Webserver doesn't work (I didn't change anything in Mailserver or Webserver, Mailserver is Exchange Mailserver and I just restarted it, nothing changed).

I tried with my localhost (127.0.0.1) and PHPMailer works well, Debug log shows AUTH type is "LOGIN". but in Webserver, Debug log shows AUTH type is "NTLM " and shows following error. Code in Localhost and Webserver is all same. I tried with my another Webserver which built in other network segment, it also works.

Debug Error:
"AUTH NTLM 250-X-EXPS GSSAPI NTLM 250-8BITMIME 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING 250-XEXCH50 250 XRDST 2021-05-09 09:27:31 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH NTLM TlRMTVNTUAABAAAABzIAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAACAAAAA= 2021-05-09 09:27:36 SERVER -> CLIENT: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful 2021-05-09 09:27:36 SMTP ERROR: AUTH NTLM command failed: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful",

```
    require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
    require_once('class.smtp.php');
    
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true); 
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    
    $mail->Host = "mail.mailserver.com";
    $mail->SMTPSecure ='starttls';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->Username = $username;
    $mail->Password = $password;
    $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
                'ssl' => array(
                    'verify_peer' => false,
                    'verify_peer_name' => false,
                    'allow_self_signed' => true
            )
    );
    
    $mail->SetFrom("username@mailserver.com", "XXXX");
    
    
    $mail->Subject = "Subject";
    $mail->Body = "OKOK";
    $mail->AddAddress("XX@gmail.com");
    $mail->Send();
```

Now I'm using gmail smtp, it works but very slow. I still want to use my own mailserver. can someone help? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed with following code:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ntlm';
$mail->Realm = "MailServerDomain";
$mail->Workstation = "WORKSTATION1";
```